# Lightroom CC sync issues

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-catalog, creative-cloud

I have 2 SSDs in my mac and have kept my photo library on my 2nd drive with the library index/catalog file on the 1st drive with no problems. I had to replace my 1st drive with a new one and ended up cloning the 1st onto a new SSD.

Now Lightroom is complaining that I have moved computers when the actual original photos are still on the 2nd drive and have not moved. Lightroom's suggestion is to backup my photos and re sync from the cloud. There's 850Gb of photos so I'm not keen to do this. Are there any other solutions I can use?

I still have the original drive so I can open a new Lightroom Library if needed and i have backups so I am not opposed to more command line hacks if that resolves the issues.

Has anybody got any ideas or suggestions?

Note it's CC (the one with the cloud library)